# How do I use text inputted into my kivy GUI as a string to use elsewhere?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I have created a very simple GUI in kivy and am trying to use it to send an e-mail to a specific user, how do I use the text inputted into the GUI as I am unfamiliar with GUI.
This is my code so far below:

```
import textwrap
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput



class Main(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2


        self.add_widget(Label(text = "Who"))
        self.Who = TextInput(multiline = True)
        self.add_widget(self.Who)


        self.add_widget(Label(text = "What"))
        self.What = TextInput(multiline = True)
        self.add_widget(self.What)


        self.add_widget(Label(text = "Where"))
        self.Where = TextInput(multiline = True)
        self.add_widget(self.Where)


        self.add_widget(Label(text = "When"))
        self.When = TextInput(multiline = True)
        self.add_widget(self.When)


        self.add_widget(Label(text = "How"))
        self.How = TextInput(multiline = True)
        self.add_widget(self.How)


class AMAPP(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()


def sendMail(FROM,TO,SUBJECT,TEXT,SERVER):
    import smtplib
    """this is some test documentation in the function"""
    message = textwrap.dedent("""\
        From: %s
        To: %s
        Subject: %s
        %s
        """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT))
    # Send the mail
    server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
    server.starttls()
    server.login('E-mail', 'Password')
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.quit()


FROM = 'me'

TO = 'you'

SUBJECT = 'test'

TEXT = (Who, What, Where, When, How)

SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'


sendMail(FROM,TO,SUBJECT,TEXT,SERVER)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    AMAPP().run()
```

whenever I run this I get the same error:

line 66, in __init__
     TEXT = (Who,What,Where,When,How)
 NameError: name 'Who' is not defined

Comment: Start by removing those diagnostic lines you put in there at some point (between the end of your sendmail function and if _ _ name _ _... line)  those are being executed even before your GUI runs!  Then put your sendmail function in your Main class.  Then add a button to your GUI to call the sendmail function.  (Then update your code here for more help)

Comment: Heads up on your textwrap.dedent call!  I was playing with this code, and found that if the string substitutions contain newlines, your dedent will not function properly.  You should dedent the format string BEFORE applying the % operator! (Just move a closing parenthesis)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give ***id*** to the Textinput widgets as you create them so that you can reference them to extract the text. Add a button so that you invoke the sendEmail method. Please refer to the example below for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
import textwrap
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


FROM = 'me'
TO = 'you'
SUBJECT = 'test'
TEXT = ""
SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'


def sendMail(FROM, TO, SUBJECT, TEXT, SERVER):
    import smtplib
    """this is some test documentation in the function"""
    message = textwrap.dedent("""\
        From: %s
        To: %s
        Subject: %s
        %s
        """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT))
    # Send the mail
    server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER, 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login('E-mail', 'Password')
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.quit()


class Main(BoxLayout):

    def send_eMail(self):
        global TEXT
        print(self.ids.Who.text)
        print(self.ids.What.text)
        print(self.ids.Where.text)
        print(self.ids.When.text)
        print(self.ids.How.text)
        TEXT = (self.ids.Who.text, self.ids.What.text,
                self.ids.Where.text, self.ids.When.text, self.ids.How.text)
        sendMail(FROM, TO, SUBJECT, TEXT, SERVER)


class AMAPP(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    AMAPP().run()
```

### amapp.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<Main>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2

        Label:
            text: "Who"
        TextInput:
            id: Who
            multiline: True

        Label:
            text: "What"
        TextInput:
            id: What
            multiline: True

        Label:
            text: "Where"
        TextInput:
            id: Where
            multiline: True

        Label:
            text: "When"
        TextInput:
            id: When
            multiline: True

        Label:
            text: "How"
        TextInput:
            id: How
            multiline: True

    Button:
        text: "Send Mail"
        on_release: root.send_eMail()
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up although I still get an error when I try to send mail: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '\__getattr__'

Comment: I was able to send email without problem using the example that I have provided. Please refer to the example for details.

Answer (score 0):

You were actually quite close with your code.  Rather than doing a rewrite to kv code (which might be better practice), I simply added the button, fixed your dedent call, added the self.Field.text references, and it worked fine.  Here's the edited code.

```
import textwrap
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button  # ADDED

EMAIL="<senders email address>"   # ADDED
PASSWORD="<senders password>"   # ADDED

class Main(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        self.add_widget(Label(text = "Who"))
        self.Who = TextInput(multiline = True)
        self.add_widget(self.Who)


        self.add_widget(Label(text = "What"))
        self.What = TextInput(multiline = True)
        self.add_widget(self.What)


        self.add_widget(Label(text = "Where"))
        self.Where = TextInput(multiline = True)
        self.add_widget(self.Where)


        self.add_widget(Label(text = "When"))
        self.When = TextInput(multiline = True)
        self.add_widget(self.When)


        self.add_widget(Label(text = "How"))
        self.How = TextInput(multiline = True)
        self.add_widget(self.How)

        self.add_widget(Button(text="Send",on_press=self.sendmail))   # ADDED

    # ADDED function callable by the button press:

    def sendmail(self,*args):

        FROM = 'me'
        TO = '<receivers email address>'
        SUBJECT = 'test'
        TEXT = '\n'.join([self.Who.text, self.What.text,
            self.Where.text, self.When.text, self.How.text])
        SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
        sendMail(FROM,[TO],SUBJECT,TEXT,SERVER) # watch out for the TO argument


class AMAPP(App):
    def build(self):
        return Main()


def sendMail(FROM,TO,SUBJECT,TEXT,SERVER):
    import smtplib
    """this is some test documentation in the function"""
    message = textwrap.dedent("""\
        From: %s
        To: %s
        Subject: %s
        %s
        """) % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT) # FIXED the dedent call
    # Send the mail
    server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(EMAIL,PASSWORD)
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    AMAPP().run()
```

Warning, it is more involved if you want to send data TO the kivy GUI, because kivy has to know the data has changed.  But that's beyond the scope of this question.